# ORA-932 Date expected, got Julian Date

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sql-update

So I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE products
(   
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR2(30),
    id_pc INTEGER,
    onStock INTEGER,
    onMarket DATE,
    CONSTRAINT fkProducts FOREIGN KEY (id_pc) REFERENCES producers(id),
    CONSTRAINT ckProducts CHECK (onStock BETWEEN 0 AND 1000)
);
```

And this is my update:

```
public void updateProducts(ArrayList<Product> collProducts) throws Exception{

    String update
            = " UPDATE products "
            + "  SET name = ?, "
            + "  onMarket = onMarket-?,"
            + "  onStock = ?"
            + " WHERE id = ? ";


    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(update, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

    for (Product prod : collProducts) {
        stmt.setString(1, prod.getName());
        stmt.setDate(2, Date.valueOf(prod.getOnMarket()));
        stmt.setInt(3, prod.getDecStock());
        prod.setDecStock(0);
        stmt.setInt(4, prod.getId());
        stmt.executeUpdate();           
    }
}
```

Every time I try to update a collection of Products the above named error occurs. My "onMarket" is already a local Date. But apparently I can't cast it to a date as a Juliandate is expected.

Comment: You are subtracting two dates -- the result of which is not a date.  It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @GordonLinoff omg thanks...... I didn't realized i exchanged onMarket with onStock....